# How to test hover menu in Jasmine (Angular Material component)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-material

I'm trying to test a hoverover menu in Jasmine.  The element I'm trying to test is one of these: https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.2/#/demo/material.components.menu

The HTML code for the menu/button itself is as follows:

```
<md-menu id="site-menu-container">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-mouseenter="Navbar.openMenu($mdOpenMenu)> {icon here} </md-button>

    <md-menu-content id="site-menu">
        .... Menu items go here
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

My stripped down controller looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp.navbar').controller('NavbarController', NavbarController);

function NavbarController() {
    this.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu) {
        $mdOpenMenu();
    }
}
```

Fyi, I'm using the controller as syntax.

For my test, I've tried a few different things.

```
it('should open menu on mouseover', function() {
    $('#site-menu-container .md-icon-button').trigger('mouseover');
    expect($('#site-menu').length).toBe(1);
}
```

This did not work.  I tested the code in my console, which works, but I guess it doesn't work that way in Jasmine.  Karma says the length is 0, not 1 as I expect.

I also tried

```
var Navbar;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    Navbar = $controller('NavbarController', {});
    spyOn(Navbar, 'openMenu').and.callThrough();
}));

it('should call openMenu on mouseover', function() {
    $('#site-menu-container .md-icon-button').trigger('mouseover');
    expect(Navbar.openMenu).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

This also did not work. I'm not even sure this is a proper situation for using spy.

Am I taking the wrong approach here? Do I need to mock `$mdOpenMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

Karma is the test runner - good :)
For testing controller and service code you use Jasmine.
For testing UI interactions (known as E2E testing in the Angular world) you use protactor.

I've done unit test using Jasmine before but never written a protractor test in my life as this is done by our test team!
Have fun learning it!

Please let me know it this was heplful or not! thanks

Comment: Ahh I see.  So what I want to test falls under E2E and not so much unit testing.  I'll give Protractor a look, thanks.  Guess I'll just have to learn both at once

Comment: An upvote would be great if this answer is accepted :) Cheers